# Openvino Loading up binary file into a blob

Tags: python, c++, intel, inference, openvino

Hi I am working on an audio classification model. I have implemented in python, now I need to port it to c++.

I do feature extraction in python as it is easier. I save these features, into a file.
The feature is represented as a 2D array in numpy.(feature is not an image but one can think of it as as an image)

I would like to load them in to an InferenceEngine::Blob. All the examples I see are loading it from an image file (actual jpeg o gif) using openCV matrix.
How can I load a binary array into a blob?
Can I load 1D array and specify its shape(width and dimension) as I load it into a blob?
If I have an int array of size 9, how can I convert it to 3x3 blob using Vino Api.

Can I / Do I have to load it to openCV matrix from a binary file?(The binary file is not an image) , Can I even do it without data being a an actual image file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inference of non-image data, you can create the blob using the [InferenceEngine::Blob classes](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/classInferenceEngine_1_1Blob.html). Here is the video on the example implementation of the Inference Engine main function call.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwgPgKClU3w

There is no specific example for an array as an input. Check out the following demos and samples for the supported models such as GNMT, BERT, TDNN, and ESPNet.

- [BERT Question Answering Python*Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_python_demos_bert_question_answering_demo_README.html)
- [BERT Question Answering Embedding Python*Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_python_demos_bert_question_answering_embedding_demo_README.html)
- [Speech Recognition Python*Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_python_demos_speech_recognition_demo_README.html)
- [Text-to-speech Python*Demo](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_python_demos_text_to_speech_demo_README.html)
- [Automatic Speech Recognition C++ Sample](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_inference_engine_samples_speech_sample_README.html)